# Colored Emojis on a JavaFx Label

Tags: java, javafx, emoji

currently working on a messaging app using javafx and i was able to set up emojis in my messages using their unicodes but only black and white emojis, i'm using a vbox with textflows, a textflow for each line and i am using Symbola font for the emoji labels and getting the following  result which is an actual screenshot from my app:

[image: screenshot]

my question is how to display colored emojis as in web browsers like  or

i checked every link i found on google or stackOverflow but none of them included a working way to display colored emojis on a javaFx application

Comment: At least two of the options listed in the link above have color icons.

Comment: no these fonts are nice but also monocolored

Comment: In one of the examples, you can see the icons have color.  I personally use FontawesomeFX so I know they have color.

Comment: Do you mean that the icons can only be yellow and not yellow, red and white?

Comment: http://fxexperience.com/2009/07/free-icons-for-your-javafx-applications/

Comment: Have you read this -> http://www.guigarage.com/2015/01/support-emojis/

Comment: that post from guigarage says there will be a second part about colored emojis but never posted again, but the link from fxExperience has given me a nice idea of using Images for icons, i will try that

Comment: fontAwesome icons can be colored, and so can be the emojis provided by symbola font, but they will only have on color, unlike emojis on android for example where they take multiple colors  , and using images sounds like a good idea right now

Comment: this is not a duplicate and if you really think so explain to me why it is